# How to get the css property of a tags in testcafe?

Tags: css, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a simple code with a structure that looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <style>label { property: value; }</style>
  <label id="id1">text</label>
</div>
```

My goal is to assert the css property whether it is equal to value of not.

I have tried using the getStyleProperty like this:

```
const sel = Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property')
```

However, it always returns undefined value, is there something that I miss?

Answer (score 5):

You probably missing `await` before `Selector` so it should be

`const sel =  await Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property')`

or

```
const sel = Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property')
await t.expect(await sel).eql(propertyValue)
```

Comment: You are quite right about the missing `await`, but there is one more remark. 
If you want to calculate Selector's property value and assign the result to a variable, use the following code: `const sel = await Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property');`

Comment: But if you don't need to save the property's value and need to use it only in an assertion, you can omit an `await` statement to use the [Smart assertion query mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism)
`await t.expect(Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property')).eql(propertyValue)` or `const sel = Selector('#id1').getStyleProperty('property'); await t.expect(sel).eql(propertyValue);`